# How to redraw NSTableView(NSScrollView) focusring?

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nstableview

What function I need to override to draw custom focus ring around NSTableView(or I need to subclass NSScrollView what contains table)? May be there are some examples of custom focus ring drawing?